Where is the Changelog and Release Notes of the Git project?
Where is the changelog and release notes of git-scm.
I checked https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/Documentation/RelNotes
But there, the latest one is 2.9.5.txt which is from 7 years ago.
I also checked https://git-scm.com/
Here, i could find only the latest Release Note.
I could not find all the changelog anywhere.
To give some context, This is to find answers to the questions like: in which version --reverse was added in git log.

They are separated by release: https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.45.0.txt, https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.44.0.txt

At the link you provided the last one currently is 2.45.0.txt, updated 3 days ago. Please remember the directory is sorted alphabetically, not numerically, that's why 2.9 is ordered after 2.4 and 2.45.

@phd is there any changelog (a file where it is mentioned, which feature was added in which version).

@AhmadIsmail You mean all Release Notes combined in one file? I don't know if such a file exists.

It would be convenient if they had a symlink latest.txt or something which pointed to the newest file.

@Guildenstern In Git it's called tags ;-)

The page you link to, this one:

https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/Documentation/RelNotes

is sorted alphabetically, not numerically.
A bit down in the page, you have this transition (as of 8th of April 2024):
...
2.44.0.txt           Git 2.44-rc2             2 months ago
2.45.0.txt           The fifteenth batch      3 days ago
2.5.0.txt            RelNotes: replace Gm...  5 years ago
2.5.1.txt            Git 2.5.1                9 years ago
...

so that is the right page, it's just sorted a bit unexpected.
Once the numbers rise to 2.50.something, you'll find those numbers below 2.5.something. So it's some slight legwork needed to find the right release notes.
